# Azure Load balancer mapping different port in load balancing rule not working

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I have created Azure load balancer with 2  linux VMs in backend pool. I have configured common NSG for both the VMS allowing port 80 and 8080. I have hosted my website in both the VMS at port 8080. In load balancing rules i have added a rule with which if i try to load load balancer Ip at port 80, it should forward the request to port 8080 of VM.
[Load balancing rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVQFm.png)

When i created last week while learning about Load balancer it was working fine.
Now that i created everything freshly, its not working. I tried to deploy using ARM template of the working resource, still no luck. Am i missing something here?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i think there would be health prob role not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your health probe appears to be set to port 80, if your backend apps are being served on port 8080, then your probe needs to be set to use that.

In this setup, the probe will be trying to talk to your VMs on port 80 and not getting a response, so it will report both machines as unhealthy, and no traffic will be sent.

Comment: I changed the port in health probe to 8080. i didn't realize it was 80. Thanks a lot